# ASP.NET MVC - Request.IsAuthenticated is false when system date is changed

Tags: asp.net, .net, asp.net-mvc

If i loged in current date initially it is successfully loged in but after that i loged out and change the system date then again try to log in IsAuthenticated is false. why?

Comment: Unclear what you are asking. Clearly having logged out you aren't authenticated until you log in again. When you "try to log in" what happens? Are you changing the date on the server or the machine browsing it?

Comment: After successfully logged out,I changed the system date and again, try to log in but it return an error after redirect to the page. (HttpContext.Request.IsAuthenticated is false) If the system date is same as with previous date when logged in successfully then it works perfectly.

Comment: it's form authentication or windows? Without Looking at login or logout method, it is hard to day what is happening

Comment: Its Form Authentication.

Answer (score 1):

In Asp.net MVC when a user logged in, a session is created for the specific user and that session has a timeout value in minutes. So when a session is created it only works for the specified amount of time and after that, the session expires.

In your case, it seems that when you change your system Date and Time the session time becomes expired (because the interval from the session was created to the current time is greater than specified session timeout value) and that's the way you are redirected to the login page. You can change your session time in two ways. You can add session attribute in `web.config` file or you can specify by `Session.Timeout`. For more information see this
[Session Timeout MSDN Reference](https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/dotnet/api/system.web.sessionstate.httpsessionstate.timeout?view=netframework-4.7.2).

**Web.config file:**

```
<configuration>  
    <system.web>  
        <sessionState   
        mode="InProc"  
        cookieless="true"  
        timeout="30" />  
    </system.web>  
</configuration>
```

**Or:**

```
Session.Timeout=30;
```

Hopefully, it will solve your problem.